# Add child to class properties in for cycle

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a problems with adding subelements off AddressElement objects

My test class:

```
    public class AddressElement
    {
       public AddressElement[] AddressElement1 { get; set; }
       public string PostIndex { get; set; }

    }
```

My test interface:

```
    public interface IAddress
    {
      string PostIndex { get; }
    }

    private AddressElement CreateAddressElement(IAddress address)
            {
                return new AddressElement
                {                
                    PostIndex = address.PostIndex                
                };
            }

    private int startIndex = 0;
    private int finalIndex = 5;
```

Get elements method:

private AddressElement[] GetAddressElements(List addresses, int startIndex, int finalIndex)
    {
          List addressElements = new List();

```
for (int i = startIndex; i < finalIndex; i++)
            {
if (i == startIndex)
                {
 addressElements.Add(CreateAddressElement(addresses[i]));

if (i != startIndex )
                {
 AddressElement addressElement = addressElements[startIndex];
addressElements[startIndex].AddressElement1 = new[] { CreateAddressElement(addresses[i]) };    

}

    I need add all subelements of AddressElement in for cycle: addressElements[startIndex].AddressElement1[startIndex].AddressElement1[startIndex].AddressElement1[startIndex].AddressElement1[startIndex]....
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you actually want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Linq :

```
private AddressElement[] GetAddressElements(List addresses, int startIndex, int finalIndex) {

  return addresses.Skip(startIndex).Take(finalIndex - startIndex).Select(s => CreateAddressElement(s)).ToArray() ; 
}
```

Hope it will help you.